# Trying to run Python on Android - With cmake

Tags: android, python, android-studio, gradle, cmake

I know this is a long shot.

So using this [GitHub Python](https://github.com/GRRedWings/python3-android) project I am currently able to run Python on Android building with an experimental version of gradle.  We are trying to upgrade to mainline gradle and the newest Android Studio, so we are trying to build all our NDK stuff with cMake. We have everything so that it will run, but as soon as we launch Python it says it fails to import _socket.

We have all the same assests and Python in the project, we have included all of the shared libraries so that thinks compile and link. Any ideas what is missing that I can't import the socket stuff?  I assume this is a c module that it's trying to import and run, but can't understand what would be different that it can't find it.

[image]

```html
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(workflow)

set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE gnustl_shared)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 23)

# configure directory variables for use throughout this file
set(distribution_dir ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs)
set(jni_src_dir ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../jni)

# set all our include directories (header locations)
include_directories(${jni_src_dir}/asr/inc
                    ${jni_src_dir}/ext/android/audioin/inc
                    ${jni_src_dir}/asr
                    ${jni_src_dir}/python
                    ${jni_src_dir}/pdd
                    ${jni_src_dir}/pdd/os
                    ${jni_src_dir}
)

# define the 3rd party libraries to include in this project
# this includes all Nuance stuff, and our custom built python lib
add_library(libgenericdca SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libgenericdca PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgenericdca.so)
add_library(libvocon3200_sem SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon3200_sem PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon3200_sem.so)
add_library(libpal_audio SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libpal_audio PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpal_audio.so)
add_library(libpal_core SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libpal_core PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpal_core.so)
add_library(libpython35m SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libpython35m PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpython3.5m.so)
add_library(libvocon3200_asr SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon3200_asr PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon3200_asr.so)
add_library(libvocon3200_base SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon3200_base PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon3200_base.so)
add_library(libvocon3200_gram2 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon3200_gram2 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon3200_gram2.so)
add_library(libvocon3200_platform SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon3200_platform PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon3200_platform.so)
add_library(libvocon3200_pron SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon3200_pron PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon3200_pron.so)
add_library(libvocon3200_sem3 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon3200_sem3 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon3200_sem3.so)
add_library(libvocon_ext_heap SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon_ext_heap PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon_ext_heap.so)
add_library(libvocon_ext_stream SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libvocon_ext_stream PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${distribution_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libvocon_ext_stream.so)

# set various C and CXX(++) flags
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fexceptions")

# recursive wildcard search to find all the right cpp and c source files to compile
file(GLOB_RECURSE source_files ${jni_src_dir}/asr/*.cpp
                               ${jni_src_dir}/ext/android/audioin/src/*.c
                               ${jni_src_dir}/asr/*.cpp
                               ${jni_src_dir}/pdd/*.cpp
                               ${jni_src_dir}/pdd/os/*.cpp
                               ${jni_src_dir}/*.cpp)
SET( workflow_source ${source_files})

# finally, set up our workflow library and attach the source files above (this causes cmake to compile the sources)
add_library(workflow SHARED ${workflow_source})
# set our workflow library to be C++
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (workflow PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

# lastly, set to link against the 3rd party libs above
target_link_libraries(workflow
                      android
                      libgenericdca
                      libvocon3200_sem
                      libpal_audio
                      libpal_core
                      libpython35m
                      libvocon3200_asr
                      libvocon3200_base
                      libvocon3200_gram2
                      libvocon3200_platform
                      libvocon3200_pron
                      libvocon3200_sem3
                      libvocon_ext_heap
                      libvocon_ext_stream
                      log
                      atomic)
```

Comment: Post Project structure and the Android CMAKE

Comment: Marcos, I have posted the structure and cmake.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Not sure if you saw that I added to the post. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did, didnt seen anything wrong in a short look, but this edit will make others able to help

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3 was released and around the same time Gradle 4.1 was released.  Now with using both of these I'm able to build and run Python without issue.

I'm assuming the Gradle 4.1 release had some change that fixed my issue.